# django - truncate output of template tags?

Tags: django

I've got a template tag that outputs text. How can I run this through truncate_words?

e.g. My search results are returned via:

```
{% get_translated_value result "text" %}
```

How can I run this through truncate_words:50 ?

The answer is (I can't update this post for a few hours):

```
{% filter truncatewords:30 %}
    {% get_translated_value result "text" %}
{% endfilter %}
```

Comment: Thanks, as I was answering you I tried one more thing and I found the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
from django import template
from django.utils.encoding import force_unicode
register = template.Library()

def truncate(value, arg = None):
    if arg:
        return force_unicode(value)[:arg]
    return value

register.filter('truncate', truncate)
```

Also some other options(haven't try them ... made my own wheel):

1. http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/163/
2. http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/194/
3. http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1471/